# Spring boot runtime @Scheduled cron parameter refresh/reload/reinitializate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, runtime

Мое приложение выполняет задания в заданное время с помощью cron. Пользователь может изменять свойства файла, состоящие из конфигурации строк cron. Когда свойства файла изменяется, Spring должен обновить конфигурацию и все модули, зависящие от этой конфигурации во время выполнения.

Я пытался что-то сделать, но не работал для меня:

1. `@RefreshScope` менял на `CronTimerConfiguration` класс.
2. `@RefreshScope` менял на `getTimer()` `@Bean` не может создать саб класс final java.lang.String. Я попробывал поменять сигнатуру метода на `public Object getTimer0()`, это скомпилировалось, но не заработало.
3. [Event based property class](https://github.com/drxaos/spring-reloading-config/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/config/SampleProperty.java). Это работало, но `@Scheduled` аннотация хочет постоянное значение поэтому я не могу юзать поля.
4. Spring-boot-devtools авто рестарт. Добавляет проперти к application.properties: `spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true` и `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=src/main/resources`. Spring перезагружается когда файл изменяется, но `foo()` метод обрашяется к старому cron значению.
5. Смена CronTimerConfiguration как здесь:
   `@NotNull
   @Value(value = "${cron.timer0}")
   public String timer0;`
6. [@PropertySource guide](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

У меня нету идей как заставить его работать? Возможно есть путь без аннотаций? Я видел классы что имитируют `@Scheduled(fixedRate ="")`, но мне нужен класс что имитирует `@Scheduled(cron ="")`.

PS Spring version 4.3.10.RELEASE

Configuration класс:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("cron")
public class CronTimerConfiguration {
    @NotNull
    private String timer0;

    public void setTimer0(String cronString) {
        this.timer0 = cronString;
    }

    @Bean
    public String getTimer0() {
        return timer0;
    }
}
```

application.properties йаил:

```
cron.timer0=0 0 */12 * * *
```

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.timer0}")
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Time now is " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"cron", "web"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37335973/6885692) через `class implements SchedulingConfigurer` и реализацию метода

```
@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            paymentService.processPayment();
        }
    }, new Trigger() {
        @Override
        public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
            String cron = new SampleProperty().getStringProp1();
            CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cron);
            return trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
        }
    });
}
```

с использованием [event-based property class](https://github.com/drxaos/spring-reloading-config/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/config/SampleProperty.java)