# Cron изменение значение через БД

Tags: java, spring, quartz

Всем привет! Необходимо реализовать cron который будет запускать потоки в определенное время. Но время запуска должно задаваться удаленно, через БД например. Как это сделать? Или есть иной подход дергать потоки? Спасибо!

Comment: это не оно? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710069/spring-boot-runtime-scheduled-cron-parameter-refresh-reload-reinitializate

Comment: Хм.. Ну почти, скажем не так гибко как я хотел, но как решение думаю сойдет. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Spring boot runtime @Scheduled cron parameter refresh/reload/reinitializate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710069/spring-boot-runtime-scheduled-cron-parameter-refresh-reload-reinitializate)